# Change IDA pro dissassembly to linear sweep

Tags: ida, disassembly

I would like to know if there is any way to modify the algorithm used in IDA pro. I have a binary where I suspect that junk isn't junk, and I would like to see what output would a linear disassembly do, but I could not find any option in IDA Pro to change that. Does it even exist? Thanks !

Comment: You can select the bytes you want and press c to interpret them as code.

Comment: @bart1e I know, this is not my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDA doesn't have a built-in linear sweep mode. You do have a couple of options though. In kernel options 2, you can uncheck coagulate code/data segments before doing the initial analysis, this will prevent IDA from converting unknown bytes into data. You could also try undefining everything, selecting everything, and then hitting C to convert it to code.

Comment: You can make idc/idapython script that marks every address as code